# Replace Empty Value to Keyboard Event

Tags: wpf, vb.net, keyboard

I'm focusing only on the keyboard up, down, right, left in WPF. And, I do not want other key event to take place. Refer to the code below, how to assign or set the other key to nothing / dbnull? I got the error at `e.Key = Nothing`

```
Private Sub Button1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Button1.KeyUp
    Select Case e.Key
        Case Key.Right
            Keyboard.Focus(Button2)
        Case Key.Down
            Keyboard.Focus(Button3)
        Case Else
            e.Key = Nothing
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`KeyEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyeventargs.aspx) [`Handled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.handled.aspx) property and set it to true. Depending on how tight you are wanting inhibit additional Keys you may need to handle the [`PreviewKeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewkeydown.aspx) Event also to filter out the <kbd>Tab</kbd> Key.

Comment: Sample source code to share out. `    Private Sub ReturnToGame_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles ReturnToGame.PreviewKeyDown
        Select Case e.Key
            Case Key.Left
                Keyboard.Focus(Button2)
            Case Key.Up
                Keyboard.Focus(Button3)
        End Select
        e.Handled = True
    End Sub`

Answer (score 2):

you could use PreviewKeyUp event and mark the e.Handled as true

Comment: Thanks for helping, the PreviewKeyDown fit better. If using PreviewKeyUp, it will actually jump twice.